# What fuzzy/glitchy around edges effect/artifact is this? & How can it be achieved?

Tags: lens, artifacts

I don't know what exactly it is but it's some kind of a blur, color separation, fuzziness and i guess it's caused by the lens.

I marked it in this image below:

[image: Dat Cool Artifact]

Comment: It can probably be achieved by using a very bad/damaged lens...

Comment: it is not right. what ever it is. it is not right.  it should NOT be achieved, EVER. I hold you personally responsible for permanently scaring my psyche.

Comment: The black "hills" at the bottom look to be caused by fingers over the lens or possibly the flash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time, i finally found out how to achieve this without modifying the lens on a DSLR. Google has a free program called [Nik Collection](https://www.google.com/nikcollection/), with that I achieved similar results:

[image: sorry for the middle finger tho...]

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a scan of an analog photo?

What i see here is blur (probably caused by a missed focus and/or a cheap compact film camera), chromatic aberration (colour fringing) (a lens defect), excessive contrast leading to over- and underexposed areas (a lighting problem), and shadows.

The left circled area shows just normal shadow, caused by the flash exposure, the arrow points to a shadow which may be caused by some obstruction, like a finger in front of the flash or lens maybe.

Answer (score -3):

Nevermind, found it!
Here it is:

[image: Coma Aberration]

It's called "Coma Aberration", but still don't know how to achieve it :/

Source:
[[Lens Characteristics: Flare, Ghosting and Aberration]](http://av.jpn.support.panasonic.com/support/global/cs/dsc/knowhow/knowhow15.html)

Comment: I'm sure it's not coma aberration. Come aberration isn't an effect or filter. It's an aberration caused by the lens.

Comment: To achieve it, you need a badly designed/constructed lens.

Comment: I think ths' answer is correct

Comment: It's probably a combination of "all of the above." Particularly Spherical Aberration, Chromatic Aberration, and Astigmatism.

Comment: None of the pictures in this answer are correct for the aberrations named.